Can Appium grid using Appium 2 / grid4 be setup programmatically?
I'm trying to migrate our java automtion framework that uses Appium 1 to Appium 2. I've been trying to setup the appium grid using grid4 programmatically but not having much luck.
For our grid3 setup we used to use the following to setup the grid:
        Hub hub;
        GridHubConfiguration config = new GridHubConfiguration();
        config.newSessionWaitTimeout = NEW_SESSION_TIMEOUT_HERE;
        config.timeout = TIMEOUT_HERE;
        config.cleanUpCycle = CLENUP_CYCLE_HERE;
        config.port = PORT_NUMBER_HERE;;
        hub = new Hub(config);
        hub.start();

The appium server was setup like this:
    AppiumDriverLocalService service;
    AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    builder.withIPAddress(ipAddress);
    builder.usingPort(portNumber);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.CONFIGURATION_FILE, NODE_CONFIG_FILE_PATH_HERE);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL,"error");
    service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
    service.start();

When using appium 2 / grid 4 I'm using the following pom dependencies:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.18.0</version>
    </dependency>

When trying t looks like GridHubConfiguration / Hub classes aren't recognised to create the hub / node configuration and looking at https://appium.io/docs/en/2.0/guides/migrating-1-to-2/#external-files-no-longer-supported-for-nodeconfig-default-capabilities-allow-insecure-and-deny-insecure it appears you can't pass in the node config through the AppiumServiceBuilder object.
I have a couple of questions:

When starting up selenium grid4 - apart from starting selenium grid hub via command line as it's suggested https://appium.io/docs/en/2.0/guides/grid/ is there a way of starting up the grid4 hub programmatically similar to GridHubConfiguration / Hub classes above?

When starting up appium server with a node configuraton - since appium 2 doesn't support --nodeconfig as above it appears you can pass the node configuration into the AppiumServiceBuilder via an appium configuration file as shown https://appium.io/docs/en/2.0/guides/config/. If I wanted to pass in the following node configuration that i was using in grid3 how would i express it in the appium config file?


{
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "appium:automationName": "uiautomator2",
            "appium:browserName": "Samsung SM-G988B/DS",
            "appium:deviceName": "Samsung SM-G988B/DS",
            "appium:platformVersion": "12",
            "maxInstances": 1,
            "platformName": "android"
        }
    ],
    "configuration": {
        "cleanUpCycle": 90000,
        "host": "HOST_VALUE_HERE",
        "hubHost": "HUB_HOST_VALUE_HERE",
        "hubPort": 4444,
        "maxSession": 5,
        "port": 4723,
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "register": true,
        "registerCycle": 5000,
        "timeout": 5000
    }
}

